# How can I cancel a 'await for' in a flutter / dart bloc

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart

I am using a stream to read out location data in a bloc. I have a start and a stop event. In the stop method, I cancel the stream subscription. When I use `listen` to a stream to `yield` the state the inside where the `yield` statement is never gets called.

```
  Stream<LocationState> _start() async* {

    _locationSubscription = location.onLocationChanged.listen(
      (location) async* {
        if (location.isNotNull) {
          yield LocationState.sendData(location: updateLocation(location));
        }
      },
    );

    //send one initial update to change state
    yield LocationState.sendData(
        location: updateLocation(await Location().getLocation()));
  }

 Stream<LocationState> _stop() async {
    await _locationSubscription?.cancel();
    _locationSubscription = null;
    yield LocationState.stoped();
 }
```

When I replace the `listen` to `await for` I don't see any way
to stop this from yielding events because the subscription handle is gone.
Any ideas? Any explanations?

```
   Stream<LocationState> _start() async* {


    await for (LocationData location in location.onLocationChanged) {
      if (location.isNotNull) {
        yield LocationState.sendData(location: updateLocation(location));
      }
    }

    //send one initial update to change state
    yield LocationState.sendData(
        location: updateLocation(await Location().getLocation()));
  }
```

Comment: I find it difficult to understand the problem here? What Stream are you trying to stop? Also, you first example are properly not doing what you expect. The provided method are calling yield which then are returning the values. But this method are defined as `void onDate(T event)` so it will throw the data away from `LocationState.sendData`. Also, a `async*` method are lazy evaluated to it will first start execution when somebody are listen on the returned `Stream<T>`. In your case, this will never happen since the method are given to `listen` which does not listen on the returned `Stream`.

Comment: For you second example, I am not sure what the problem is. The `Stream` returned from `_start()` must be listened to before the code inside `_start()` will start executing. And when you are listening on this `Stream` you will get a `StreamSubscription` which you can cancel which will stop the code inside `_start()` to run.

Comment: On the Second example -
If the stop event gets called I would like to cancel the stream setup in the start method. There is no stream subscription I can cancel. So the question is how to stop the 'await for'
The first example - 
Yes you are right it does not work. Do you have a fix for that?

Comment: Where does this stop-event come from (your second example does not contain any traces of this)? Also, it is rather difficult to give any advice when you have not given a complete working example.

Comment: ok added the stop method.

Comment: @RideSun . I had the same question,could you put your solution ? Thanks.

Comment: see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that I did not understand the behavior of yield completely.
Also, the dart framework has some shortcomings.

The problem was discussed in detail with the dart makers, here.

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/42717

and here

https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/1472